# An instance of Class A is a public member of Class B and instance of B is also a public member of A. When do we need this implementation?

Tags: java, oop

An instance of Class A is a public member of Class B.  An instance Class B is also a public member of A.  In what scenarios this kind of implementation might be needed?  I mean is there a standard scenario or scenarios this kind of  implementation is needed?
More specific details: 
I have a list view adapter that has an auxiliary tag (a data holder without any methods) and that auxiliary tag has the adapter as a member.

Comment: looks like bidirectional one-to-one relation

Comment: @Boris: added more specific details of my situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example if we had two classes: `Employer` and `Employee`, then `Employer` would have an `Employee`, and the `Employee` has the `Employer`.

However that architecture could cause troubles called [*`Circular dependency`*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency)

Comment: Thank you.. added more specific details of my situation